# Apache2 Virtual Hosts not recognizing properly

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have two virtual hosts, but apache seems to be defaulting to one of them.

Here is host #1:

```
<VirtualHost *>

        ServerName goiclub.com
        ServerAlias www.goiclub.com *.goiclub.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/casey/public_html/goiclub/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/casey/public_html/goiclub/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>



        ErrorLog /home/casey/public_html/goiclub/log/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog /home/casey/public_html/goiclub/log/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        Alias /doc/ /usr/share/doc/
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the other vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin webmaster@geticlub.com
ServerName geticlub.com
ServerAlias www.geticlub.com *.geticlub.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /home/casey/public_html/geticlub/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/casey/public_html/geticlub/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /home/casey/public_html/geticlub/log/error.log
CustomLog /home/casey/public_html/geticlub/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

whether I type in goiclub.com or geticlub.com it returns 'geticlub.com' vhost. Does anyone know why?

Also this might be helpful:

```
sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 50.56.118.158 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                    geticlub.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/geticlub.com:1)
*:*                    goiclub.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/goiclub.com:1)
```

Comment: are these domains present in your /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need NameVirtualHost set up.

Open ports.conf and add: (You can also put it above the first `<virtualHost>`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

You can also use the ip address instead of the wildcard.

Your vhost has to be formatted exactly the same as the NameVirtualHost format.

If it's formatted like this:

`NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8080`

then vhost should be:

`<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8080>`