# Apache virtual hosts not working

Tags: apache-http-server

I am having trouble in making virtual hosts in Apache to work. The virtual hosts were running fine but suddenly it stopped working today. To create virtual hosts I opened the *httpd-vhosts* file and typed in the configuration like one below:

```
<VirtualHost hello.dev:80>
ServerAdmin xyz@ty.com
DocumentRoot "H:\www\hello_webservice"
ServerName hello.dev
ServerAlias www.hello.dev
ErrorLog "logs/hello.dev-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/hello.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way the apache is working since I am able to access htdocs via localhost.

Comment: have a look at apache error log

Comment: Do you have an entry for hello.dev in your host file or DNS server? Apache doesn't automatically configure your network. First get `ping hello.dev` to work from the command line then setup your vhosts.

Comment: Also, see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/286923/apache2-virtual-hosts-not-recognizing-properly?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On Windows:

```
httpd.exe -k restart
```

Comment: -1 Judging by the OP host file, this person is using Windows. Notice the location of `DocumentRoot`? You also had the command wrong, I've fixed that though.